# Message passing between trusted page content and addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm unable to pass messages between a trusted page-worker script, and the addon.

main.js:

```
var pageWorkers = require("sdk/page-worker");
var self = require("sdk/self");

// Create a page worker that loads Wikipedia:
pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: self.data.url("html/worker.html"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
        console.log("within onAttach");
        worker.port.on("message", function() {
                console.log("Message received");
        });
        worker.port.on("message", function(message) {
                console.log("Message received1");
        });
  },
  onReady: function(worker) {
        console.log("within onReady");
        worker.port.on("message", function() {
                console.log("Message received");
        });
  }
});
```

worker.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../js/worker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

worker.js:

```
    console.log("trying to emit message");
    addon.port.emit("message");
    addon.port.emit("message", "value");
    console.log("tried to emit message");
```

In main.js, If I try the following outside of the `pageWorkers.Page()` call:

```
pageWorkers.port.on("message", function() {
        console.log("Message received");
});
```

I get the following exception:

```
Message: TypeError: pageWorkers.port is undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried using postMessages to no avail. If asked, I can add that code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page workers, like tab attaching and unlike pageMods, don't have an `onAttach` function. Nor do they have an `onReady`, since the contentScriptFile is automatically attached when the HTML is ready.

### main.js

```
var worker = pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: self.data.url("html/worker.html")
});
worker.port.on("message", function() {
  console.log("Message received");
});
//If your events have the same name then they're the same event,
//irrespective of arguments passed
worker.port.on("message1", function(message) {
  console.log("Message received1");
});
```

### worker.js

```
console.log("trying to emit message");
addon.port.emit("message");
console.log("trying to emit message1");
addon.port.emit("message1", "value");
```